# How to get 2-nd set of data string?

Tags: sql-server

I tried that:

```
SELECT [ConstituentID]
,ColumnName
,SUBSTRING(ColumnName, 1, CHARINDEX('/', ColumnName)-1) AS ColPart01,
SUBSTRING(ColumnName, CHARINDEX('/', ColumnName) +1, 100) AS ColPartREST
FROM TableName
```

But I am able to split it into 2 parts only, any chance you know, how can I get second set of data using SubString and Charindex?

So: "1-2/456/£25.00-26.00/56/10+" I split to 2 columns. Col01: "1-2" and ColPartREST: "456/£25.00-26.00/56/10+". If I want to identify second set: "456" how can I do it? Number of symbols vary time to time in all sets, only delimiter is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

Use APPLY and follow the same pattern:

```
SELECT t0.[ConstituentID]
    ,t0.ColumnName
    ,t1.ColPart
    ,t2.ColPart
    ,t3.ColPart
FROM TableName t0
CROSS APPLY
    (SUBSTRING(t0.ColumnName, 1, CHARINDEX('/', t0.ColumnName)-1) AS ColPart
    ,SUBSTRING(t0.ColumnName, CHARINDEX('/', t0.ColumnName) +1, 100) AS ColumnName) t1
CROSS APPLY
    (SUBSTRING(t1.ColumnName, 1, CHARINDEX('/', t1.ColumnName)-1) AS ColPart
    ,SUBSTRING(t0.ColumnName, CHARINDEX('/', t1.ColumnName) +1, 100) AS ColumnName) t2
CROSS APPLY
    (SUBSTRING(t2.ColumnName, 1, CHARINDEX('/', t2.ColumnName)-1) AS ColPart
    ,SUBSTRING(t0.ColumnName, CHARINDEX('/', t2.ColumnName) +1, 100) AS ColumnName) t3
```

But if you have lots of sections (more than just s few) better would be to use one of the many String_Split functions.

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName t
CROSS APPLY dbo.String_Split(t.ColumnName,'/') s
```

Comment: Thank you very much, can I please kindly ask what are these "t0, t1...." mean? Actually what I desire is to select some data using Substring and Charindex, save it as column (virtually, not physical column) and select data from this selection.

Comment: t0, t1, are table aliases. Try making a view of this - aliasing the ColPart columns as ColPart1, 2, 3, etc.